# problems with oauth2-server-laravel

Tags: php, laravel, oauth

I'm new to OAuth. I'm trying to implement https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel#password-flow

I've already inserted `id` and `secret` into `oauth_clients` table. Also I have inserted username and password into `users` table. (via Phpmyadmin)

After I try to do the request:

```
POST http://localhost:8000/oauth/access_token?
grant_type=password&
client_id=weredfsdfsrq341&
client_secret=dfwefsdf&
username=test@test.com&
password=123456
```

But response is:

```
{
error: "invalid_request"
error_description: "The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed. Check the "client_id" parameter."
}
```

My route is

```
Route::post('oauth/access_token', function()
{
    return AuthorizationServer::performAccessTokenFlow();
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Same probleme, do you have a solution? I'm upgrading v1 to v3

Comment: Stuck with same issue: "The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed. Check the \"grant_type\" parameter."

tried to change to x-www, same result

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether you found the answer to this, but, this is a bug in the package as discussed here [Here](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/issues/225)

Basically when the content type is json the parameters are not handled correctly by the package.
Fix:
Locate `$authorizer->setRequest($app['request']);` in vendor/lucadegasperi/oauth-server-laravel/src/OAuth2ServerServiceProvider.php
and add this line **just above it**

```
 $app['request']->replace(\Input::all());
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the content type is set to "x-www-form-urlencoded" when you make that POST.

Comment: How do I store the access_token, so obtained, to a variable ?

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I think you missed the parameter `scope`. Just a guess.